# Compare data from a List in a Range of Data and Display value from 3rd column

Tags: vba, excel

May I ask something.

I have `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` on `Sheet2` I have 2 `Coumns` name `Outlet Name` and `Outlet Code` (Based on there headers)

Now I used `Outlet Name` Columns to create a list in a cell in `Sheet1` lets say `A1` so the `A1` now has a list and below it is `B1` obviously. Now here is my question.

How can I display the `Outlet Code` in `B1` when the the selected in the list versus in `Sheet2` are same. like this.

`IF(A1=Sheet2ListOfOutletNames,B2=Sheet2ListIfOutletCodes)`

something like that i hope someone help me with this one TYSM

Comment: can you add screenshots of your data and expected result? What have you tried so far?

Comment: sir all done TYSM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in B1 type the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A1:B10,2,0)
```

where you hae to change `Sheet2!A1:B10` with actual range first column and second column of which have, correspondingly, list of outlet codes and list of outlet names (in my examples I assumed this range is A1:B10)

Comment: How I wish I accept both of your answers all correct TYSM

Comment: if answers are identical, a criteria could be the fastest!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use VLOOPUP

```
 =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A2:B10,2)
```

Assuming you have names and codes in the rage A2:B10 ( adjust as needed)

Comment: How I wish I accept both of your answers all correct TYSM